# jQuery/Javascript - Trying to call value from multidimensional array using another value on the same level

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

here is the array and relevent code:

```
galleryTypes = [];
galleryTypes[0] = ['basements', 3];
galleryTypes[1] = ['bathrooms', 8];
galleryTypes[2] = ['customcarpentry', 7];
galleryTypes[3] = ['desksporches', 8];
galleryTypes[4] = ['flooring', 5];
galleryTypes[5] = ['historicrestoration', 6];
galleryTypes[6] = ['kitchens', 6];

$(document).ready(function () {

    startNow = setInterval(forwardImage, 4000);

    var GalleryName = $('.GalTitle').attr('id');
        alert(GalleryName);

for( var galResult = 0, len = galleryTypes.length; galResult < len; galResult++ ) {
    if( galleryTypes[i][0] === GalleryName ) {
        return galResult;
        break;
    }
}

    alert(galResult);
```

I would like to find a function that will allow me to find the index of the first array in which the string sits. IE: basements would return 0 and flooring would return 4.

I will go on to use the index to get at the second part of the second array, like basements would eventually lead me to 3 and flooring to 5. I don't want to go directly there as I need to use the index to find items in yet another array later on.

Thank you very much for any help you can give me. I would like to use code that will be supported by most browsers. This current code does not even post the second alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple, create a function and iterate:

```
function findWord(word) {
    for (var i = 0; i < galleryTypes.length; i++) {
        if (galleryTypes[i].indexOf(word) > -1) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

If `-1` is returned, the item doesn't exist.

```
var index = findWord("flooring"); //returns 4
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I wish I could 1up this answer. still new here, learning little by little

Answer (score 0):

Have made some tiny changes to @tymeJV

Use this function

```
function findSiblings(array,keyword,shiftPosition){
    var iterator = array.length;
    for(var i=0;i<iterator;i++){
        if(array[i].indexOf(keyword) > -1 && typeof(array[i].indexOf(keyword) + shiftPosition) !== 'undefined') return array[i][array[i].indexOf(keyword) + shiftPosition];
    }
    return -1;
}

var sib = findSiblings(galleryTypes,'flooring',1);
console.log(sib);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
startNow = setInterval(forwardImage, 4000);
```

Start now broke everything.  What are you trying to do here? I removed it and made the changes below and got 4 returned.

The reason why the second alert never fired is, you were returning galResult in the if statement, but never calling a function.  Just alerting the variable.

Also you iterating over galResult but using [i][0] in the is statement.  Also the closing paren and bracket were left off the the .ready fucntion.  No biggie there tho.

I set GalleyName to flooring in my function, you should be able to set it back to retrieving the value of GalTtile.
    $(document).ready(function () {

```
var GalleryName = "flooring";
alert(GalleryName);
var foo = function() {


    for( var galResult = 0, len = galleryTypes.length; galResult < len;   galResult++ ) {
        if( galleryTypes[galResult][0] === GalleryName ) {
            return galResult;
            break;
        }
    }
};
alert(foo());
});
```